# what is the granularity of the iPhone 4S timer?

Tags: iphone

Since the iPhone4S is reported to have a 800MHz clock , it might be that the timer has a 200MHz (5nsec) granularity? Anyone know what the shortest loop period might be?

Answer (score 4):

From the [NSTimer reference page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html):

> Because of the various input sources a typical run loop manages, the
>   effective resolution of the time interval for a timer is limited to on
>   the order of 50-100 milliseconds. If a timer’s firing time occurs
>   during a long callout or while the run loop is in a mode that is not
>   monitoring the timer, the timer does not fire until the next time the
>   run loop checks the timer. Therefore, the actual time at which the
>   timer fires potentially can be a significant period of time after the
>   scheduled firing time.

Again, though, that's for NSTimer, which you generally use for triggering events that should happen at certain times or time intervals. If you're trying to measure elapsed time you can likely get a much more accurate result than 100ms, but I don't see a documented accuracy in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Try including mach/mach_time.h, mach_time() seems to provide microsecond resolution timing vales or better, and doesn't have non-monotonicity problems as NSDate does.

Comment: +1 This is what I was looking for -- I was sure you could measure time with much better accuracy than you get from NSTimer, but I'd forgotten where to look.